# OptaPlanner: How is data used during runtime?

Tags: optaplanner

I'm exploring the OptaPlanner project and experimenting with a modified (simplified) version of the Cloud Balancing use case just so I can wrap my head around the mechanics.

- If I have a cloud computer with 64GB of memory and the engine assigns a process that consumes 32GB of memory, is the engine aware of the fact that I have 32GB remaining on the cloud computer in its decision making?  Or, is this requiring me to explicitly apply that logic within the class that implements the EasyScoreCalculator class?  I'm not clear how far I can take the EasyScoreCalculator child without knowing how the data is being used.
- In this example the @PlanningVariable is an object.  Can a @PlanningVariable Elements of an array within an object?  My brain is swelling with ideas the more I peel this solution back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is this requiring me to explicitly apply that logic within the class that implements the EasyScoreCalculator class?

No, you only have to check if no more than 64GB is used on that computer
Think google search: your task is to define *what* to search for, now *how* to search for it.
Or in optaplanner's case: your task is to *score* every solution optaplanner finds, not *how to search* for solutions.

> Can a @PlanningVariable Elements of an array within an object?

Not yet, not until we support `@PlanningVariableCollection`. Meanwhile we have chained variables (see VRP etc)...